# How to adjust .htaccess for multi-part URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to get my code to accept an URL like the following:

www.mysite.com/something/something2/something3/something4

I have used the following code in my .htaccess so requests are run through an index.php file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This works fine if the url is www.mysite.com/something.

However, if I change it to www.mysite.com/something/something2 I get a problem loading external files such as CSS.

Instead of loading the requested CSS file, it loads index.php.

This is only if there is more than 1 segment after the domain. Otherwise, it loads the CSS just fine.

Here is how I am loading the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: You'll need to use an absolute path rather than a relative one, i.e. `"/style.css"`

Comment: That worked. Feel free to post it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're telling Apache to treat all URIs as `index.php`, all your paths will need to be absolute, or relative to `index.php`. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

*(Originally commented)*

Comment: BTW - The single '/' before the file name didn't work. I had to change it to a fully qualified URL like www.mysite.com/style.css

Comment: Interesting. Try changing the last line of your .htaccess to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`.

Comment: Also, is the .htaccess at the root of your site?

Comment: Yes, it is in the root directory of the site.

Comment: Yes, absolute URLs always work, however it's still odd to me that paths relative to the root of your site don't.